# os.walk error of unhandled stopIteration

Tags: python, os.walk

I have written a python script and wanted to debug it using eric ide. When I was running it, an error popped up saying `unhandled StopIteration`

My code snippet:

```
datasetname='../subdataset'
dirs=sorted(next(os.walk(datasetname))[1])
```

I am new to python and so, I don't really know how to fix this. Why is this error popping up and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) will generate file names in a directory tree walking it down. It will return the contents for every directory. Since it is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) it will raise `StopIteration` exception when there's no more directories to iterate. Typically when you're using it in the `for` loop you don't see the exception but here you're calling [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) directly.

If you pass non-existing directory to it will immediately raise the the exception:

```
>>> next(os.walk('./doesnt-exist'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

You could modify your code to use `for` loop instead of `next` so that you wouldn't have to worry about the exception:

```
import os

for path, dirs, files in os.walk('./doesnt-exist'):
    dirs = sorted(dirs)
    break
```

The other option is to use `try`/`except` to catch the exception:

```
import os

try:
    dirs = sorted(next(os.walk('./doesnt-exist')))
except StopIteration:
    pass # Some error handling here
```

Comment: Okay! But how could I fix this?

Comment: @Sibi Added couple examples to answer

Comment: Yes, that error has been resolved but now I'm getting a new error two lines below in `leng=len(dirs);` saying `"name 'dirs' is not defined"`

Comment: @Sibi If you're using `for` loop you could do `dirs = None` before the loop. With try except you could do the same within except block. Then if `dirs` is `None` later you know that it didn't exist. If you're ok with considering non-existing and empty directory the same you could assign empty list to `dirs` instead of `None`. Since I can't see the rest of the code I can't really tell what's the "correct" approach.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, python 3.6, `next(os.walk(whatever_directory))` raised a `StopIteration` exception because `whatver_directory` was actually a file.