# extracting sub_folders of a path in python using next(os.walk(path))[1]

Tags: python, subdirectory, stopiteration

I have a python program and in my program, I want to manipulate folder and subfolders. When I use `subfolders = next(os.walk(src))[1]` command, I get this error:

```
StopIteration
```

I have no idea about this error. I print the path before rising the error and the path is valid.

Comment: Apparently, `src` does not exist. Do a print to see what it is.

Comment: This post might be of help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289653/os-walk-error-of-unhandled-stopiteration

Comment: To understand this in more depth, python iterators will raise a StopIteration exception when they are empty. So in effect what is happening is the iterator is out of available items.

Comment: @zondo As I said in my question, I am printing src content and this is a valid path.

Comment: @pypyoy unfortunately I could not get a list if my subdirectories in my giving path.