# How to resolve os.walk error in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

```
def getFiles(_root):
    return next(os.walk(_root))[2]

root = "../../../Image/new_m/"
fileList = getFiles(root)  # return file list
fileList = sorted(fileList)
```

I get this error every time I try to run my function which is supposed to get files from my folder.
The error shows `StopIteration` every time I try to run it.

Comment: Maybe use `os.listdir` instead? Do you understand what `StopIteration` means? How to resolve it depends on what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289653/os-walk-error-of-unhandled-stopiteration

Comment: Possibly related: [Why am I getting a FileNotFoundError?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17658856/4518341)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @mkrieger1 I want to run the code till it reaches its end in the directory. I know what os.walk means but i dont knw how to use it here. P.S. my program is aimed at identifying a fake currency for Indian bills using edge detection segmentation, etc. So if posssible reply I will share with you and resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import os
def getFiles(_root):
    try:
        return next(os.walk(_root))[2]
    except StopIteration:
        return []  # Return an empty list if the iterator is empty

root = "../../../Image/new_m/"
fileList = getFiles(root)
fileList = sorted(fileList)
```

You can try the above-mentioned code. It will resolve your issue.